# what's the method to creating a dynamically sized panel with scrollbars

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a level editor for a game, you standard platformer. By default the level size is 24_Height & 32_Width both multiplied by a tilesize of 32. So by default the Panel container size is 1024 x 768.

You can change the rows and columns with the windows form which re-sizes the panel. This is where I'm running into an issue. The default size looks fine, but when increasing its size, the panel itself isn't locked to the current size and instead extends in both Width and Height respectively.

What I want is for it to be locked in its default size and have scroll bars appear in the appropriate locations when the Panel gets any bigger than default.

For this reason, I have looked at the autoscroll option in the events tab, but setting it to true doesn't seem to make a difference (as it doesn't appear even if the panel leaves the form). I looked at changing the max size value (currently 32000, 32000) thinking I could still re-size it by code but not have it visible in the form the same way. It didn't work.

[image: http://img4host.net/upload/2305134050aef7f46b283.png]

[image: http://img4host.net/upload/2305174350aef8e7b580f.png]

The paint code if it's necessary, though it's very empty considering I just started this project.

```
private void MapPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (MapPanel.Width < (oMapGrid.TileColsValue * oMapGrid.TileSizeValue))
        MapPanel.Width = (oMapGrid.TileColsValue * oMapGrid.TileSizeValue);

    if (MapPanel.Height < (oMapGrid.TileRowsValue * oMapGrid.TileSizeValue))
    {
        MapPanel.Height = (oMapGrid.TileRowsValue * oMapGrid.TileSizeValue);
        MapPanel.AutoScroll = true;
    }

    for (int Row = 0; Row < oMapGrid.TileRowsValue; Row++ )
    {
        oPen_and_Brush.ClassGraphics.DrawLine(oPen_and_Brush.ClassPen, 0, Row * oMapGrid.TileSizeValue, MapPanel.Width, Row * oMapGrid.TileSizeValue);
    }
    for (int Col = 0; Col < oMapGrid.TileColsValue; Col++)
    {
        oPen_and_Brush.ClassGraphics.DrawLine(oPen_and_Brush.ClassPen, Col * oMapGrid.TileSizeValue, 0, Col * oMapGrid.TileSizeValue, MapPanel.Height);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".